# Ajax Post Throwing Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, post, controller

The ajax post hits the server and delivers the correct information, but even though it works it still is hitting the error function. The ready state is 0, so it says it isn't even making the request.

```
            var serviceURL = '/ContactForm/FirstAjax';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: JSON.stringify(formInfo),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                            alert("Worked");
                        },

                error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                    alert("Failed to process correctly, please try again" + "\n xhRequest: " + xhRequest + "\n" + "ErrorText: " + ErrorText + "\n" + "thrownError: " + thrownError);

                }
            });
```

The error message is:[image: Error Msg]

My controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("FirstAjax")]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public JsonResult FirstAjax(ContactForm contactForm)
    {            
        return Json("works", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Check xhrequest.responseText

Comment: It didn't do anything. I logged it in console but im not sure how to interpret what it says. The ready state = 0 and so does the status.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your ajax post method or your controller. 
If you leave the ajax method as is, you can modify your controller to:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("FirstAjax")]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public JsonResult FirstAjax()
{            
    var postedData = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
    var jsonEncoded = postedData.ReadToEnd(); //String with json
    //Decode your json and do work. 
    return Json("works", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you don't want to change the controller, then you need to change the javascript to:

```
var serviceURL = '/ContactForm/FirstAjax';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: { contactForm: JSON.stringify(formInfo) },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
                     alert("Worked");
                },
        error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("Failed to process correctly, please try again" + "\n xhRequest: " + xhRequest + "\n" + "ErrorText: " + ErrorText + "\n" + "thrownError: " + thrownError);

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both, still getting an error. With what I had it was passing the object correctly, and I was able to use it in the controller. But even with it working, the error would show. The ready state from it is 0 which means it didn't initiate the request, could it be firing too fast?

Comment: It can be a cross-domain issue: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818939/jquery-post-respond-with-readystate0-status0, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586780/jquery-ajax-post-unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I was using Fiddler and realized it was doing a `GET` not a post `POST`. I figured it out how to fix it. When I submitted the form, it called the Javascript with `onsubmit="submitForm();"`. By submitting the form it was preforming a `GET` on the url instead of a `POST`. I fixed with `onsubmit="submitForm(); return false"`.

Answer Source - [jQuery: why does $.post does a GET instead of a POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271490/jquery-why-does-post-does-a-get-instead-of-a-post)